# Persisting objects from external classes (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

what is the best way to persist objects from external classes? There are no getters and setters implemented. Moreover that the class didn't implement Serializable.

Best Regards

Comment: Can you provide more details? what is the class you trying to store objects. It would be great if you provide more information. Also please state whether you need to persist it or to cache it?

Comment: It's EncryptedNumber.java from javallier (homomorphic encryption). You can find it here: https://github.com/n1analytics/javallier/tree/master/src/main/java/com/n1analytics/paillier. I want to store as many objects as possible in a database.